# Unix putting extra spaces/lines while passing values to sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, plsql, ksh

I have a unix script like this:

```
value1=`sqlplus -s ivr/ivr <<EOF  
set heading off;  
set feedback off;  
set linesize 500;  
set serveroutput on;  
set wrap off;  

SELECT FM.getSequence_n('$b_period', '$t_period', '$opr', '$fran', '$poi_s') 
  FROM DUAL;  

exit;  
EOF`  ,
```

The parameters are taken as input from the user. when i run the script in debug mode using 'ksh -x filename.sh'  i notice that when the unix script is passing values to the select statement it breaks it like this:

```
SELECT FM.getSequence_n('  
      2010/12/01 - 2010/12/31','  
      2010/12/01 - 2010/12/31','TTSLAP','UWAP','TTSL-LOC') 
  FROM DUAL
```

...which gives the wrong output. When i run the same sql statement with the passed values in sqlplus with all the values in a single line i get the correct output.

I need to know why unix is breaking the statement into multiple lines and how can this be removed. This has been giving me nightmares. Firstly i was thinking that values were not being passed correctly that's why output was wrong . But only this linefeed by unix while passing values is the cause of error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `$b_period` and `$t_period` variables contain newline characters. If they are input directly from users you really should do some [input validation first before using them](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Try something like

```
filtered_b_period=`echo $b_period | sed 's/[^0-9\/]*//g'`
filtered_t_period=`echo $t_period | sed 's/[^0-9\/]*//g'`
```

Probably you should add further check as well, but at least you should be able to filter out unwanted characters this way.

Comment: the b_period and t_period have value :'2010/12/01 - 2010/12/31' , now when i use the method suggested by you, the sql query is now getting parameters in single line only but now the problem is that the the sed removes the '-' as well as the single space following and trailing the '-'. How do i make sure that only the unnecessary spaces from the beginning get removed and not these?  Please suggest.

Comment: removing trailing and leading spaces using 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' worked.  Thanks for suggesting sed.

Comment: oh sorry, an oversight in my search pattern. To include `-` as a valid character not to be removed, put it either as the very first or very last character within `[...]`, e.g. `sed 's/[^-0-9\/]*//g'`.

Answer (score 0):

The values of your variables include newlines. Do something like this to check:

```
echo "$b_period" | hexdump -C
```